# Azure Function GET request getting 401, but POST works

Tags: azure, https, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that has a GET endpoint and a POST endpoint.  In local testing they both work fine.  When published to Azure, the POST endpoint works with the copied link from the Functions blade ('https://address/api/search?code=xxx'), but a GET request to the same endpoint returns 401 Unauthorized.  Anyone else have this issue, or an idea on how to get this working?  I've tried restarting the Function app, re-publishing, and stop-starting the app.  All result in the same issue.

EDIT: Just for clarity, I'm using POST to do a detailed search with search terms included in the body, and GET to just retrieve all items.

EDIT2: I also see that the function.json visible in the Functions blade shows the following:

```
..."bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "route": "search",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ],
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req"
    }
  ], ...
```

So it looks like my GET endpoint didn't even make it into the published function. This works locally with two functions sharing an endpoint, but differing request types, but doesn't seem to work in Azure.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out.  The functions in the Functions blade are listed by function name, not endpoint.  I had built the functions in Visual Studio, so the compiler required unique names for the functions, which made sure I was naming them properly.  I just missed the fact that each function name was separate, regardless of endpoint.